# How to add pagination to dynamic table created from textbox values?

Tags: javascript, html

The below code adds rows from textbox values. I need to limit number of rows to 10 in a page and display next rows in pagination format. User can enter page number to navigate or prev, next buttons. I tried using Datatables plug in but couldn't get it to work for this case. It worked fine when the table content was static ie all tr, td's defined in code. 
Any other ideas to implement pagination here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>HTML dynamic table using JavaScript</title> <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script> </head> <body onload="load()">   <div id="myform"> <b>Simple form with name and age ...          </b> 
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="name" value="" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="button" id="add" value="Add"></td></tr><tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table></div><div id="mydata"><b>Current data in the system ...</b> 
<table id="myTableData" border="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr> <td>&nbsp;</td><td><b>Name</b></td><td><b>Sr no</b></td></tr>
</table>&nbsp;<br/></div><div id="myDynamicTable"></div>
</body> </html>
```

Javascript:

```
 function renumber() { 
     var table =           document.getElementById("myTableData"),  srnos=document.querySelectorAll(".srno")
    for (var i=0;i<srnos.length;i++) {
srnos[i].innerHTML=(i+1);
 } 
 } 
function addRow() {
   var myName =        document.getElementById("name").value;
    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
     var rowCount = table.rows.length;
     var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
      row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = '<input         type="button" value = "Delete"       onClick="deleteRow(this)">';
       row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = myName || "";
        row.insertCell(2).innerHTML =     row.rowIndex;
    row.cells[row.cells.length-1].className="srno";
 }
function deleteRow(obj) {
    var index =  obj.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
     var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
 table.deleteRow(index);
 renumber();
   }
     function addTable() {
     var myTableDiv =  document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");
     var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
     table.border = '1';
     var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
     table.appendChild(tableBody);
     for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
      for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement('TD');
       td.className="srno";
      td.width = '75';
             td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Cell " + i + "," + j));
     tr.appendChild(td);
     }
   }
   myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
   renumber();
   }
 window.onload=function() {
    document.getElementById("add").onclick=addRow;
   console.log("Page load finished");
   }
```

Comment: What is the data source?  User input?

Comment: Yes, user input from the textbox

Comment: You might save the names to an array.  Then use an index to track the current position, forward and backward.  When the position changes update your table to display 10 array elements starting at the index.  People are more likely to answer questions when someone tries to code a solution and then asks for help with specific problems. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)